# Moment.js - How To Display Every "Next Thursday" Only

Tags: date, momentjs

I want to display the date on a webpage. Only showing the next coming Thursday at 6pm PST.

So, no matter what day or time the visitor comes to the page, they should always see the next Thursday 6pm PST coming up.

How can I do that with Moment.js?

Also, is there a way to integrate a countdown timer with moment.js to do that, so the visitor would always see the time counting down to that moment?

Thanks!!

Comment: Something like: `Today.AddDays(Thursday.DayOfWeek - Today.DayOfWeek).StartOfDay.AddHours(18)`

Comment: Best to avoid adding hours to the start of the day. Due to DST transitions, this could be 5 PM or 7 PM, not just 6 PM. Granted DST transitions don't generally happen on Thursdays, but who wants to find a bug years from now when the government makes a weird decision?

Answer (score 0):

This takes a little thought, and requires the use of moment-timezone since you want to know the time in America/Los_Angeles no matter where in the world the user is. Steps are:

- Create moment for now in in America/Los_Angeles
- Use setters to explicitly set time to 6 PM on Thursday this week
- Check if now is before that date
- If so, value is this week Thursday
- If not, value is seven days later

The code:

```
var thisThursday = moment().tz('America/Los_Angeles').isoWeekday(4).hour(18)
                     .minute(0).second(0).millisecond(0);

var date = (thisThursday.isSameOrAfter(moment())) ? thisThursday 
              : thisThursday.add(7, 'days');
```

Note that `date` is still in the America/Los_Angeles time zone. If you want to display it in the user's local time, you can pass it's value back into a new moment:

```
moment(date.valueOf())
```

To do your countdown timer, I would have a look at what is laid out in moment-countdown: https://github.com/icambron/moment-countdown